# Sharepoint REST API - SP.Web.CreateAnonymousLink - Unable to CREATE Links

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sharepoint-rest-api, postman, anonymous-access

In short - the issue appears to be that I can access a folder or file's anonymous link - but only after it's been created. When I say created - I mean clicking the 'copy link' button as show in the screen. (Also works fine if a Flow creates it)

[image: Creating Anonymous link]

If that's been done, then using the REST API to get the anonymous link works fine:

**Header**

[image: Request header]

**Body**

[image: Request response]

**Response**

[image: Request body]

If I try and 'create' a link for a new file though;

**Bad response**

[image: Bad response]

So where are my permissions failing me? You may have noticed that I don't pass the X-RequestDigest. That's because it doesn't seem to do anything. Without it I can upload and do whatever I need - with it, I gain no new permissions.

The app that I'm using to authenticate against has what I think is full control over the SharePoint site. As seen in [this page's](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs) example:

[image: Xml example]

Is there anything I'm missing? Why wouldn't I be able to create an anonymous link through the API but I can access it if someone else has already created it?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.

Started working for me when I updated app permissions to

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true"> <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" /> <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" /> <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="Read" /> <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" /> </AppPermissionRequests>
```

Comment: This is someting I checked - I have a feeling some of my permissions went arwy. I ended up re-making the app and used it. Will accept this as the answer - because I'm fairly sure this is where my issue lied...

Answer (score 0):

Only

```
"< AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true" > 
< AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests >"
```

is needed. No need for tenant level permissions